# Qt and opencv app not working in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyqt5

I created a GUI app using pyqt5 and opencv. The app works fine without activating the virtual env but when I activate the virtual env and run the app it shows this error:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x125b2f0) is not the object's thread (0x189e780).
Cannot move to target thread (0x125b2f0)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/deepak/Desktop/SampleApp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.

Aborted
```

I tried running an example pyqt5 code (without importing opencv) and another code (only using opencv) both worked fine in the virtual env.

Operating System: Parrot OS 4.11

Python Version: 3.9.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the version of Qt with which opencv was compiled is not similar to the one used by PyQt5 causing a conflict.

A possible solution is to indicate to use the Qt plugins used by PyQt5.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget # others imports
import cv2

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = os.fspath(
    Path(PyQt5.__file__).resolve().parent / "Qt5" / "plugins"
)
# ...
```

For PySide2:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import PySide2
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget # others imports
import cv2

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = os.fspath(
    Path(PySide2.__file__).resolve().parent / "Qt" / "plugins"
)
# ...
```

### Update:

A better option is to use QLibraryInfo to get the plugins folder path:

```py
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import QLibraryInfo
# from PySide2.QtCore import QLibraryInfo

import cv2

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = QLibraryInfo.location(
    QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath
)
```

Comment: Finally. This is the way. Spent a good few hours on this. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way of solving this without changing the code? I've tried to set that env variable but it seems that importing `cv2` changes it back. I tried also to symlink the `plugins` folder from `.../site-packages/cv2/qt/plguins`  to the PyQt5 one `../site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plguins`  (which worked on Ubuntu 20.04), I tried to do it in Arch recently and it didn't work (maybe I need some other dependency?)

Comment: It did not work  in my situation.

Comment: this answer completely without uninstall anything.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by downgrading the cv2 version, simply run

> python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25

I used to have the 4.5.3.56

Comment: I have the same problem and it tells me "ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25". I am forced to install 4.5.3.56, which gives me the same error. Would you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @fatbringer In general, it is not an error, it is classified as a warning message, because for me it was showing this msg but it still works fine. As long as the code is working fine, you can just disable this warning by doing this: [On Ubuntu]
1. Go to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf 
2. Uncomment the "WaylandEnable=false"

Then restart the PC

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to remove all the openCV you have in your environment

`pip uninstall opencv-python opencv-python-headless opencv-contrib-python`

then just install

`pip install opencv-python-headless`

Comment: I think there's also a `opencv-contrib-python-headless` but I really hope nobody knows about that.

Comment: v2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'